# foreach loop not displaying any output in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, foreach

I am running a very first foreach loop in jsp. I dont know what the problem is. Its not showing any errors as well.

This is my java code:

```
package pack1;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class jstlClass

    {
        String emp_name;
        String emp_id;
        String emp_dept;


        public String getEmp_name()

        {
            return emp_name;
        }
        public void setEmp_name(String emp_name)

        {
            this.emp_name = emp_name;
        }
        public String getEmp_id()
        {
            return emp_id;
        }

        public void setEmp_id(String emp_id)
        {
            this.emp_id = emp_id;
        }

        public String getEmp_dept() 
        {
            return emp_dept;
        }

        public void setEmp_dept(String emp_dept) 
        {
            this.emp_dept = emp_dept;
        }

        public static void main(String[] gs)
        {
            ArrayList li=new ArrayList();

            jstlClass emp=new jstlClass();
            emp.setEmp_id("20");
            emp.setEmp_name("vishnu");
            emp.setEmp_dept("it");
            li.add(emp);

            jstlClass j=new jstlClass();
            j.setEmp_id("21");
            j.setEmp_name("prem");
            j.setEmp_dept("csc");
            li.add(j);

        }   
    }
```

This is my jsp code:

```
<html>
</head>
<body>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<jsp:useBean id="emp1" class="pack1.jstlClass" scope="session"/>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>

<% 
<c:forEach var="li" items="${sessionScope.li}">

<c:out value="${li.emp_id}"/>
<c:out value="${li.emp_name}"/>
<c:out value="${li.emp_dept}"/>

</c:forEach>

%>

</body>
</html>
```

I have tried for so long but still it shows the same output. I am using Eclipse and Apache Tomcat server. I even tried running it in google chrome server, but no changes. I have put that "Hello world" in there and its displaying that, but not entering the foreach loop.
This is my first foreach loop program and i have absolutely no idea what is going wrong.
Help please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not at all right... You are doing it worng...
You will have to read servlet jsp before doing this...

for your project create a servlet and pass data from servlet to jsp and then only jsp can access data from there

Try servlet jsp examples first..
Example servlet

```
public class Login extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Login() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
                      //right your code here to get data from jstlClass and pass it to the jsp in request
      request.setAttribute("","");
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/FirstJSP.jsp").forward(request, response);                
        } 

protected void doget(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        }       
        }
    }
}
```

and then you can access the parameters there

Try this example
   http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=552

Comment: it wont change until you learn the right way... please read about servlet and jsp

Comment: check the link in the edited ans and try the example given there it will help you

Comment: @Varsha it is possible to get the values from the class , just like `obj.methodName` . it is valid from servlet 3.0

Answer (score 0):

you have to set properties of your class in the JSP.

reason is main method is not called in j2ee prespective:

Try This

```
<jsp:useBean id="emp1" class="pack1.jstlClass" scope="session"/>
 <jsp:setProperty name="emp1" property="emp_id" value="20"/> 
 <jsp:setProperty name="emp1" property="emp_name" value="vishnu"/> 
 <jsp:setProperty name="emp1" property="emp_dept" value="it"/>
```

access using  tag:

```
  <jsp:getProperty name="emp1" property="emp_name"/>
```

Comment: set properties to what?

Comment: I want to access the properties i have set in my java code in my jsp file. I want to set the properties in java and display on browser using jsp..