# JSP Iteration not Displayed

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web-applications

I am passing a list from the servlet to JSP as follows:

```
Agent agent = (Agent) request.getSession().getAttribute("agent");

List<Message> messageList = agent.mailbox.getMessages();
request.setAttribute("messageList", messageList);

request.getRequestDispatcher("/message.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Then, I am iterating it in the JSP file as follows:

```
<c:forEach items="${sessionScope.messageList}" var="msg">
    <tr>
        <td>Agent ID: <c:out value="${msg.getID()}"/></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

The web app executes and works fine, no errors etc... However, the output from the list is not being displayed.

Comment: check this line present on top of jsp page `<%@ page session="true" %>`

Comment: take a look at this pls. It may solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26652712/foreach-loop-not-displaying-any-output-in-jsp

Comment: @ArvindKatte Yes the line is present.

Comment: @javatar Can't see how I can replicate that answer to my issue.

Comment: `HttpSession session = request.getSession(); session.setAttribute("messageList", messageList); ` and delete this line `request.setAttribute("messageList", messageList);`, in your servlet class

Comment: @ArvindKatte Tried it as well, still no output.

Comment: which version servlet container you use? Maybe `${msg.ID}` instead of `${msg.getID()}`.

Comment: @GurkanYesilyurt I am using Servlet 4.0. And no it has to be `${msg.getID()}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## I needed to install JSTL to use the code.

1. Download the Jar Files from [here](https://app.box.com/s/gzz2nyf9s506d3h3vkzq) and put them in your WEB-INF/lib folder.
2. If you are using maven add the dependency.
3. Add the taglib on top of your JSP page: `<%@  taglib  prefix="c"   uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" 
   %>`
4. Rebuild the Project

Now you can use the JSTL in your JSP.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting a request attribute, but iterate on `sessionScope.messageList`.

Use `requestScope.messageList`, or simply `messageList`.

Comment: Tried the change, but still the same issue

Comment: Then it probably means that the message list is empty. Use your debugger.

Comment: It is not empty, I debugged the servlet and the messageList is not empty.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a HTML issue? Have you checked the generated HTML (i.e. selected view page source)? Have you printed the messageList directly in the JSP using ${messageList}?

Comment: Using `${messageList}` in the JSP works. But what could be the issue with HTML?

Comment: Maybe you're putting your table rows outside of an actual table.